# Execute loop while commands is running

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop

I want to create a loop (blinking LED) while a command (in this case ping) is running.
I am using the Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

```
while [ `nmap -p 80 example.com` ] # something like this
    do 
    echo "1">/sys/class/gpio/...
    sleep 0.2
    echo "0">/sys/class/gpio/...
    sleep 0.2
done
```

Comment: Perhaps you could run ping as a child process, and have the parent process do the light-blinking whilst it waits for the child to finish what it's doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would do :

```
any_command & _pid=$!
while kill &>/dev/null -0 $_pid; do
    echo "1">/sys/class/gpio/...
    sleep 0.2
    echo "0">/sys/class/gpio/...
    sleep 0.2
done
```

- `kill -0` just test if the pid exists =)
- the command `any_command` is launched in the background
- `&` put the command in the background
- `$!` is the integer of the pid of the latest backgrounded job

Comment: +1, nice. But why do you put the "&>/dev/null" in such a weird place?

Comment: And maybe change the test by some use of `jobs | grep any_command` as the pid *could* be reused

Comment: @OlivierDulac I like to place `&>/dev/null` here, that demonstrate this possibility. And your command will have a bigger footprint than mine.

Comment: Yes, no subshell needed, indeed